# Need assistance making a batch file for renaming files in separate folders

Tags: batch, rename, batch-rename

Ok, here's one for you.  I'm trying to use a batch file to rename a bunch of files, but none of them are in the same folder as the batch file itself.  The command prompt keeps telling me that the directory can't be found.  I suppose I could just rename all the files in all the folders that match the filename, but I don't want to do that either; I only want to change certain ones.

My batch file as it stands is:

```
@echo off
ren "engine/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "gravplating/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "HAWX content/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "laserz/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "NeuroNaval/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "NeuroPlanes/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "NeuroTanks/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "NeuroWeapons/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "WAC Base/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "WAC DamageSystem/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "WAC GravityController/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "WAC Helicopters/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "WAC Sweps/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "weapons/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "AFF_ships/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "AntiTakeRifle/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "Catmull-Rom Cameras/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "Displacer Cannon/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "Drumdevil's Trains/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "EVEOnline/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "gm_botmap_v3/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "gm_construct_flatgrass_v5-2/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "gm_mobenix_v3_final/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "gm_mobenix_v3_highquality_Water/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "gm_snabbansairfield_b1/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "gm_XhS_construct/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "linedraw/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "ModelManipulator/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "NeuroCars/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "Propeller Engine/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "VanDookie and Predaaator's pack/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "WAC ECM/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "WAC Extra Helicopters/info.txt" "disabled.txt"
echo Done!
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to consider:

1. You should use backslash () to separate between path parts parts, not forward slash (/).
2. It is assumed that all the directories you specified are located in the same directory as your script, and that your run your script from the same location as the directories.

So, I recommend correcting it as follows:

```
rem CD to the directory in which this script is located:
CD "%~dp0"

rem 'Use' '/', not '\'
ren "gravplating\info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "HAWX content\info.txt" "disabled.txt"
ren "laserz\info.txt" "disabled.txt"

rem [...]
```

Comment: Unless the questioner is using one of the DOSes, which is unlikely given the use of non-8.3 filenames there, the use of forward slash as a pathname component separator is perfectly fine.  It is explicitly supported in pathnames by at least one operating system that "batch files" could run on — the very operating system that you are assuming with that `CD` command, in fact.  And since the command arguments are all quoted and not absolute pathnames, there isn't the concern that it might be confused with a command option, either.

Comment: JdeBP,

I am not sure what you mean.

I don't know how to write multi-line comments here, so please read this:

http://pastebin.com/DkdnVwMs.

Comment: Erm...huh?  I'm not entirely sure I understand...

Comment: There are a few lines in my answer. Tell me exactly what you don't understand.

BTW, anybody knows how can I be notified by email on comments as well as answers to a given post?